# Where to store parve such as fish, in meat or dairy refrigerator?

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk, appliances

Where to store parve such as fish: in meat or dairy refrigerator? Basically trying to figure out whether three refrigerators are needed in a kosher kitchen.

Answer (score 6):

Only one refrigerator is needed in any Kosher kitchen. [Meat and Dairy can be stored in the same refrigerator](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=900). See also [here](http://www.kashrusmagazine.com/magazine.php?do=160).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14685