# Does food need to be double-wrapped for the fridge?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, home-house

I am familiar with the idea ( [What's the halachic advantage of double (or triple) wrapping food?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9297/whats-the-halachic-advantage-of-double-or-triple-wrapping-food) ) that double-wrapping is necessary for a halachic separation in certain kashrus contexts. However, does this apply only to hot/liquid food? Or must one also double-wrap food before placing it on a countertop or in the fridge (i.e., with food that is either non-kosher or of the other moiety)?

Comment: My understanding from reading the article is that the main problem comes from the steam / vapors, which would not occur with cold items. It may be a question if you place hot soup into the fridge where cold items are. For that matter, perhaps by that logic, what if you have an open hot pan of lasagna on your kitchen counter. Can you put the pan of hot chicken on top of it?

Comment: FWIW I just wait till the food cools and never place it on the 'wrong' counter on principle. But if it comes down to 2 wraps or 3 it would probably take a Ravs interpretation. Some variables may come into play that we are not privy to such as how thick is the wrap? Did you wrap it around the entire bowl / pot or is it clinging to the top. Imo to be 'sure' you would need a rav.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14685

Comment: @Yossi What about the fridge? Are separate shelves enough, or should one double-wrap, too? Thanks

Comment: I have separate drawers and shelves and I wrap each shelf in aluminum foil. Then wrap and contain everything on its dedicated shelf / drawer

Comment: @Yossi I'm impressed and somewhat surprised. Even the frummest people I know don't wrap their shelves

Comment: I am makhmir gadol!!

Comment: @Yossi baal teshuvah?

Comment: No I'm ger. The wife as well. @SAH

Comment: @Yossi Wait do you mean convert or Gerrer chosid? Could be either I guess...

Comment: I mean we are both converts. Actually not even converted yet. We have moved three times and spent maybe 6 years trying to find someone willing to help with classes and beit din but still nothing.

Comment: @Yossi  That's amazing. You guys are amazing. If it is what Hashem wants, it will happen. And if/when you do convert you will be a model for the rest of us; perhaps you already are. P.S.--Have you tried your local Chabad House? They won't be beit din for you but can often sponsor/help.

Comment: I did try chabad. I moved here specifically for Chabad but here it is 6 months later and he won't even respond to emails or phone calls. Kinda crazy this conversion process. I think it needs an overhaul and to be addressed. There is even a mikveh here and a beit din. So pretty frustrating to say the least.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33410/discussion-between-sah-and-yossi).